# React-native community Geolocation not able to import

Tags: react-native, geolocation, npm-install

i have been trying to add location functionality to my app and i have been trying to use the official @react-native-community/geolocation package for it. but it keeps erroring out.

i have installed it `npm install @react-native-community/geolocation`
`The package '@react-native-community/geolocation' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: (Device)

- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo managed workflow
  `

1. i have reinstalled it
   2)deleted node_modules and reinstalled.
   3)tried it in expo online.
   4)tried using require.

i have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

This package working fine on my project.

First remove `node-modules` and `yarn.lock` or `package.lock` file too.

Lets add `"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2"` in package.json

and install all dependencies using yarn or npm: `yarn or npm i`

now import the `Geolocation` from `'@react-native-community/geolocation'` and use it.

**Example**

```
export const getLocationService = async (
  getCurrentLocationSuccess,
  getCurrentLocationFailure,
) => {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      const location = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        long: position.coords.longitude,
      };
      getCurrentLocationSuccess(location);
    },
    error => {
      getCurrentLocationFailure(error);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      timeout: 10000,
      maximumAge: 10000,
    },
  );
};
```

Call this function anywhere in your app like this

```
import {getLocationService} from '../locations';

 const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    getLocationService(getCurrentLocationSuccess, 
    getCurrentLocationFailure);
  };
```

When successfully get location

```
  const getCurrentLocationSuccess = res => {
    console.log('Single road 2 double 0:', JSON.stringify(res));
  };
```

When fail to get location

```
  const getCurrentLocationFailure = error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  };
```

uninstall the previously app installed on your device and rerun application after gradlew clean.

Hope it will solve your problem.